# React trigger button sound onKeyPress issue

Tags: reactjs, onclick, event-handling, keypress, onkeypress

I'm learning React and working on building a [drum machine](https://react-drum-machine.surge.sh/). I'm having issues triggering sounds on button click using onKeyPress. The buttons and sounds worked fine when clicked with the mouse, but in order to get them to work on keyboard press you first have to click that button with your mouse.

It seems like once you click a button that buttoned stays focused until another button is clicked with the mouse.

How can I use onKeyPress to trigger buttons with keys? Is onKeyPress not the correct way to handle something like this?

It appears this is an issue pertaining to buttons being focused upon when clicked.

Here is the code:

I have a drum display component where each button/div looks like this:

```
    <DrumPad
      id='Q'
      soundName='Heater 1'
      sound="https://s3.amazonaws.com/freecodecamp/drums/Heater-1.mp3"
      buttonClicked={props.buttonClicked}
      name={props.name}
      handleClick={props.handleClick}
      onKeyPress={props.onKeyPress}
    />
```

Then in another component I have a drum pad component that sets up each button and it's functionality:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';


const DrumPad = (props) => {
  return (
    <div className="drum-pad"
      onClick={() => props.handleClick(props.id, props.soundName)}
      onKeyPress={() => props.handleClick(props.id, props.soundName)}
      tabIndex="0">

      <audio className="clip" id={props.id}>
        <source src={props.sound} type="audio/mp3" />
      </audio>
      <span>{props.id}</span>

    </div>
  );
}


export default DrumPad;
```

My App.js main component is simple and consists of local state and a handleClick function to handle button clicks:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import './App.css';
import DrumDisplay from './DrumContainer';
import MySlider from './Slider.js';
import handle from './Slider.js';
import Slider, { Range } from 'rc-slider';
import 'rc-slider/assets/index.css';
import 'rc-tooltip/assets/bootstrap.css';
import Tooltip from 'rc-tooltip';

class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      buttonClicked: '',
      name: ''
    }
  }

  handleClick = (e, name) => {
    this.setState({ buttonClicked: e })
    this.setState({ name: name})

    const sound = document.getElementById(e);
    sound.volume = 1;
    sound.play();

  }


  render() {
    return (
      <DrumDisplay
        buttonClicked={this.state.buttonClicked}
        name={this.state.name}
        handleClick={this.handleClick}
        onKeyPress={this.handleClick}
      />
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

Been stuck on this button onKeyPress issue for a while. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: I'm not sure, but I think you'd better check DrumDispay component has a focus, after your react component is rendered or  mounted.

Comment: How would you recommend doing that?

Comment: You can do like it. (It is just pseudo code, that's because I don't know your sistuation exactly)


`
class DrumDisplay extends React.Component {
    componentDidMount() {
        this._wrapper.focus();
    }

    render() {
        return <div tabIndex="0" ref={ e => this._wrapper = e }></div>
    }
}
`

I think that if DOM Element you attached key event listeners has no focus, you can input key on it.

Comment: Oops, code I wrote in my comment looks broken ㅜ-ㅜ. I believe you can beautify it.

Answer (score 0):

Too late to the party, but started to learn html/css/javascript/react and therefore just in-case it helps some-else, here is a solution based on this code with some modifications.

I called onKeyPress on the div without any arguments, described it on the main App using event only and added ComponentDidMount() and ComponentWillUnMount() to handle the event listener.

It works and passes the test. The only challenge still is that, you have to click the buttons first in order for pressing keys to work....... Still learning and might solve this in the future. Otherwise suggestions are highly welcomed.

https://codepen.io/Mz12/pen/qBrwwXd

```
import React from "https://cdn.skypack.dev/react"
import ReactDOM from "https://cdn.skypack.dev/react-dom"

const descriptionStyle={
  position: 'absolute',
  width: '400px',
  height: '25px',
  top: '12.5%',
  left: '50%',
  margin: '-25px 0 0 -25px',
  textAlign: 'center'
}

const styles = {
  border: '1px solid black',
  position: 'absolute',
  width: '400px',
  height: '200px',
  top: '50%',
  left: '50%',
  margin: '-25px 0 0 -25px',
  backgroundColor: '#E6E6FA',
  display: 'grid',
  gridTemplateColumns: 'auto auto auto',
  gridGap: '50px'
};

const displayStyle = {
  border: '1px solid black',
  position: 'absolute',
  top: '50%',
  width: '400px',
  height: '50px',
  top: '35%',
  left: '50%',
  margin: '-25px 0 0 -25px',
  backgroundColor: '#E6E6FA',
  textAlign: 'center',
  fontSize: '25px',
};

const buttonStyle ={
  textAlign: 'center',
  fontSize: '25px',
  fontWeight: 'bold'
};

const developer={
  position: 'absolute',
  width: '400px',
  height: '25px',
  top: '80%',
  left: '50%',
  margin: '-25px 0 0 -25px',
  textAlign: 'right'
}

class DrumMachine extends React.Component{
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    
    this.state={
      display:''
    };
    
  this.drumItemClick = this.drumItemClick.bind(this);
  this.drumItemPress = this.drumItemPress.bind(this);
    
  };

drumItemClick = (event, text) => {
      document.getElementById(event).play();
      this.setState((state) => {
      return {display: text};
    });
      
    };
  
  drumItemPress = (event) => {
    const key = event.key.toUpperCase()
    if('QWEASDZXC'.includes(key)){
      document.getElementById(key).play();
    };
      
  };
  
  ComponentDidMount(){
    document.addEventListener("keydown", this.drumItemPress)
  };
  
  ComponentWillUnMount(){
    document.removeEventListener("keydown", this.drumItemPress)
  };


render(){

return(
    <div id="drum-machine">
    <div style={descriptionStyle}>
      <h1>Drum Machine</h1>
      <p>Click or Press Keys to Play!</p>
    </div>
    <div id="display" style={displayStyle}>
      {this.state.display}
    </div>
    <div>
      < Heaters 
        drumItemClick={this.drumItemClick}
        drumItemPress={this.drumItemPress}
        />
    </div>
    <div style={developer}>by Mz.</div>
  </div>
);


 };
};

const Heaters = (props) => {



const drumItems=[
 
  {
   buttonId: "Heater1",
   buttonClass: 'drum-pad',
   buttonText: 'Q',
   audioId: "Q",
   audioSound: "https://s3.amazonaws.com/freecodecamp/drums/Heater-1.mp3",
   audioClass: 'clip',
  },
  
   {
   buttonId: "Heater2",
   buttonClass: 'drum-pad',
   buttonText: 'W',
   audioId: "W",
   audioSound: "https://s3.amazonaws.com/freecodecamp/drums/Heater-2.mp3",
   audioClass: 'clip',
  },
  
   {
   buttonId: "Heater3",
   buttonClass: 'drum-pad',
   buttonText: 'E',
   audioId: "E",
   audioSound: "https://s3.amazonaws.com/freecodecamp/drums/Heater-3.mp3",
   audioClass: 'clip',
  },
  
   {
   buttonId: "Heater4",
   buttonClass: 'drum-pad',
   buttonText: 'A',
   audioId: "A",
   audioSound: "https://s3.amazonaws.com/freecodecamp/drums/Heater-4_1.mp3",
   audioClass: 'clip',
  },
  
   {
   buttonId: "clap",
   buttonClass: 'drum-pad',
   buttonText: 'S',
   audioId: "S",
   audioSound: "https://s3.amazonaws.com/freecodecamp/drums/Heater-6.mp3",
   audioClass: 'clip',
  },
  
   {
   buttonId: "OpenHH",
   buttonClass: 'drum-pad',
   buttonText: 'D',
   audioId: "D",
   audioSound: "https://s3.amazonaws.com/freecodecamp/drums/Dsc_Oh.mp3",
   audioClass: 'clip',
  },
  
   {
   buttonId: "KicknHat",
   buttonClass: 'drum-pad',
   buttonText: 'Z',
   audioId: "Z",
   audioSound: "https://s3.amazonaws.com/freecodecamp/drums/Kick_n_Hat.mp3",
   audioClass: 'clip',
  },
  
   {
   buttonId: "Kick",
   buttonClass: 'drum-pad',
   buttonText: 'X',
   audioId: "X",
   audioSound: "https://s3.amazonaws.com/freecodecamp/drums/RP4_KICK_1.mp3",
   audioClass: 'clip',
  },
  
   {
   buttonId: "ClosedHH",
   buttonClass: 'drum-pad',
   buttonText: 'C',
   audioId: "C",
   audioSound: "https://s3.amazonaws.com/freecodecamp/drums/Cev_H2.mp3",
   audioClass: 'clip',
  },
  
];



return(
    <div style={styles}>
           {
        drumItems.map((drumItem) => 
            (
              <button 
              id={drumItem.buttonId} class={drumItem.buttonClass}
                onClick={ () => props.drumItemClick(drumItem.audioId, drumItem.buttonId) } onKeyDown={props.drumItemPress} style={buttonStyle}>
            {drumItem.buttonText}
            <audio id={drumItem.audioId} src={drumItem.audioSound} class={drumItem.audioClass}></audio>
            </button>
            )
              )
                }
      
          </div>
      );
    };
    
    
    ReactDOM.render(<DrumMachine />, document.getElementById('root'));
```